# Blood flow problem using the continuity equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, fluid-statics, flow

**Blood flow increases during exercise by the dilation of blood vessel diameter together with an increase in
blood pressure. Suppose that the flow rate increases by a factor of 4.5 and blood pressure increase by
40%. Calculate the factor by which the average blood vessel diameter must have increased to produce this
flow. Assume that blood is a Newtonian fluid.**

In this question, I tried to solve it by the continuity equation but it did not work. We took in the class only the continuity equation but I noticed that it can be solved by an equation called: Hagen–Poiseuille equation.

I don't know what that is but can anyone help me solving this problem? and can you please tell me a strategy to solve any smiliar kind of problems when I face tomorow (I have final exam tomorrow) xDDD

Comment: Blood is an incompressible fluid. So the continuity equation applies. Show us what you tried? You don't need HP here.

Comment: Assume laminar flow (that's what the Hagen-Poiseuille equation is for), look at the variables in that equation, and solve algebraically.  Also, the continuity equation ALWAYS applies, even for compressible flows, because it describes conservation of mass.